# JOIN ON subselect returns what I want, but surrounding select is missing records when subselect returns NULL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a table where I am storing records with a Created_On date and a Last_Updated_On date.  Each new record will be written with a Created_On, and each subsequent update writes a new row with the same Created_On, but an updated Last_Updated_On.

I am trying to design a query to return the newest row of each.  What I have looks something like this:

```
SELECT 
   t1.[id] as id,
   t1.[Store_Number] as storeNumber,
   t1.[Date_Of_Inventory] as dateOfInventory,
   t1.[Created_On] as createdOn,
   t1.[Last_Updated_On] as lastUpdatedOn
FROM [UserData].[dbo].[StoreResponses] t1 
JOIN (
      SELECT 
         [Store_Number], 
         [Date_Of_Inventory], 
         MAX([Created_On]) co, 
         MAX([Last_Updated_On]) luo 
      FROM [UserData].[dbo].[StoreResponses] 
      GROUP BY [Store_Number],[Date_Of_Inventory]) t2
   ON 
      t1.[Store_Number] = t2.[Store_Number] 
      AND t1.[Created_On] = t2.co 
      AND t1.[Last_Updated_On] = t2.luo 
      AND t1.[Date_Of_Inventory] = t2.[Date_Of_Inventory]
WHERE t1.[Store_Number] = 123 
ORDER BY t1.[Created_On] ASC
```

The subselect works fine...I see X number of rows, grouped by Store_Number and Date_Of_Inventory, some of which have luo (Last_Updated_On) values of NULL.  However, those rows in the sub-select where luo is null do not appear in the overall results.  In other words, where I get 6 results in the sub-select, I only get 2 in the overall results, and its only those rows where the Last_Updated_On is not NULL.

So, as a test, I wrote the following:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE NULL = NULL
```

And got no results, but, when I run:

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 1 = 1
```

I get back a result of 1.  Its as if SQL Server is not relating NULL to NULL.

How can I fix this?  Why wouldn't two fields compare when both values are NULL?

Comment: DUUUR! I just realized, in Ansi SQL NULL is not equal to NULL, but "NULL is NULL".  I did an OR (t1.xxx IS NULL AND t2.xxx IS NULL) in the ON predicate, and now I seem to be getting the right answers.

Comment: "Why wouldn't two fields compare when both values are NULL" - because NULL != NULL. Anything compared to NULL is UNKNOWN (with default ANSI NULLS setting)

Comment: @Mitch Wheat, yeah, it's been a LONG week.  Starting to look cross-eyed at this code.  But, basically that was my "DOH!" moment as soon as I hit Post.

Comment: If you are allowed to, you could make your life easier by making Last_Updated_On default to GetDate() for every record, so that your initial records for a group have Last_Updated_On = Created_On and you have no nulls for Last_Updated_On.

Comment: @Forester 's suggestion is great. It will improve performance and simplify code!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Coalesce (example  assuming Store_Number is an integer)

```
   ON 
      Coalesce(t1.[Store_Number],0) = Coalesce(t2.[Store_Number],0)
```

Comment: This is actually how I ended up solving it, but took me a while to get there on my own.

Answer (score 1):

The ANSI Null comparison is not enabled by default; NULL doesn't equal NULL.
You can enable this (if your business case and your Database design usage of NULL requires this) by the Hint:

```
SET ansi_nulls off
```

Another alternative basic turn around using:

```
ON ((t1.[Store_Number] = t2.[Store_Number])  OR 
(t1.[Store_Number] IS NULL AND t2.[Store_Number] IS NULL))
```

Executing your POC:

```
SET ansi_nulls off
SELECT 1 WHERE NULL = NULL
```

Returns:

```
1
```

Answer (score 1):

This also works:

```
AND EXISTS (SELECT t1.Store_Number INTERSECT SELECT t2.Store_Number)
```